# Chrome bug or expected behavior?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I had to troubleshoot some HTML code recently, where I wanted to provide form data that would be frequently copied and pasted.  Usually, customers would just double-click on the identifier and press CTRL-C.  I formatted my code like this:

```
<label>Identifier</label><div>ABCD1234</div>
<label>Description</label><div>Some descriptive words</div>
```

All was well and good until the Description needed to wrap and I wanted it to not wrap below the label.  So, I added some CSS, which I'll show as inline here.

```
<style>
.fixform label { min-width: 76px; }
.fixform div { display: inline-block; width: 210px; padding-bottom: 3px; }
</style>
<div class="fixform">
    <label>Identifier</label><div>ABCD1234</div>
    <label>Description</label><div>Some descriptive words</div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, this made it so that when I double-click on the identifier, "ABCD1234", it highlighted both "ABCD1234" and the preceding word, "Identifier".  Similarly, I could double-click the word "Description", and it highlighted both "Description" and the first word, "Some".  The logic seems to be that "inline-block" treats the last word of the label and the first word of the div as a single word.

My solution was to add a space to the end of the text inside the label, but it seems kind of hackish to me.  Is there a better way to display labelled content that word-wraps like a column without the odd double-click behavior in Chrome?

Comment: `label` should be referring to an `input`. Apart from that, if you place the elements one each line in the markup it will work as you expected. https://jsfiddle.net/2371x18x/

Comment: Unless you really want them to be "glued" together when displaying.

Comment: When I have a "view" mode or "edit" mode, I use `label` for both.

Comment: Got it. Makes sense then.

Comment: I don't want them to be "glued", but when I'm setting widths, padding, and background colors, the whitespace can sometimes be a nuisance.

Comment: This happens on Firefox as well. It does indeed seem to have something to do with the lack of whitespace, coupled with the fact that labels are displayed inline by default. Highlighting has always been strange.

Comment: My current version of Firefox doesn't do that (32-bit 54.0.1), at least not for this specific scenario.  Same with my current versions of Edge and IE.  Maybe it varies across versions?

Comment: @MelanciaUK I think you nailed it.  If I separate the elements with whitespace, it doesn't insert a space between them and does separate how double-click behavior works.

Comment: That's the expected behaviour when using `inline` or `inline-block`. If you want the elements to have space between them you need to either "separate" them in the markup (ie: one each line, spaces in between) or apply `margin`.

Comment: This article has some useful info: [What’s the Deal With Display: Inline-Block?](https://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `display:table;`

```
.fixform{
  display: table;
}
.fixform label {
  min-width: 76px;
  display: table-cell;
}
.fixform div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 210px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

Comment: That might do the job.  I'm a little on-the-fence about it, though.  I haven't quite convinced myself that using display: table and display: table-cell is any less egregious than using <table> for layouts.

Comment: I think <table> and display:table; is totally different.

Comment: Tried it.  The label-div pairs keep getting appended to the right instead of below the prior ones.

Comment: https://codepen.io/hunzaboy/pen/brpKzo can you recreate the issue you are facing.

Comment: I saved changes.  I think your solution fixes one problem and creates another.  When I double-click a label, it no longer grabs a word from the div.  The problem is each label+div combo should render on its own line, but now render sideways all on one line.  I don't usually work with "display: table" enough to know how to fix it.

Comment: Well i thought you don't need the identifier to be selected. As per your question you only wanted the div to be selected. Am i missing anything?